# Updating SQLite values periodically

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, sqlite

Say I have the following four records (assume there are more):

```
        record 1      record 2      record 3         record 4

area    California    Texas         California       California

food    Lobster       Lamb          Rabbit           Bagels

popular Bagels        Elk           Rabbit           Rabbit
```

Right now I am adding new records into the database by manually choosing an `area` and a `food`. The `popular` field is then automatically populated by finding the most common `food` for that specific `area` at the time of entry.

For example, if the above four records were the ONLY records in the entire database, then if I were to add another record with `area: California` and `food: Bagels` then `popular` (for the record I just added) would automatically be assigned the value `Bagels` because there would be two `Bagels` in the `food` field, for the area `California`.

The above is already working, which I achieve the above with the following code:

```
popular = list(ModelData.objects.filter(area=area).values_list('food', flat=True))
Counter(popular).most_common()
```

The problem is, the above still leaves existing records in the database with the incorrect `popular` value; because `popular` is only calculated at the time of entry, and never 're-calculated' when more entries are added.

Using the above example (adding a new record with `area: California` and `food: Bagels`), there would still be two `California` records (`record 3` and `record 4`) which would have an incorrect `popular` value - they should be updated to `Bagels` when `Bagels` became the new, most popular food for `California`.

How would one go about updating the `popular` values for each `area`, to be the new, most popular `food`, whenever it changes (or periodically, i.e. hourly / daily)?

I have tried searching online, unsurprisingly without any luck, as I realise it is quite a confusing question.

Comment: Something like `cron` could run the update periodically. Something like `celery` could queue up requests to recalculate popular pages when key information changes. Please remember that SQLite can only run one update transaction at a time, so if your re-calculation takes a long time, at that time your DB will become effectively read-only.

Comment: @9000 I have tried something similar using the `schedule` library, however it uses a `while True` loop, so I don't understand how I can use that when the code needs to be repeatedly called, but it can't because it's stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a URL handler that does the housekeeping you want.
- Make that URL only available internally (e.g. require a token or check the requester's IP).
- Add a [`cron` job](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) (as in `man 5 crontab`) that does `curl https://your-server/internal/run-houskeeping` periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I would use celery this will help you schedule your updates and works well with Django or you could just add a script to your crontab as well.

Comment: Do you happen to have any guides on how to use Celery for this type of problem?

Comment: The celery Docs is a useful resource. Look up this link.http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html